# Update query with select statment

Tags: sql, forms, sharepoint, ms-access-2010

I have a linked SharePoint List in Access 2010 and I would like to update this list with an Update query. After the updated query it should show the Result how the table look like. How I can design this query? and I would like to pass the values for the updated table via a Form. How can I talk with form values to the query?

Best regards

Matthias

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the button in form name "Update". On the commandClick() you can use the SQL query to update the record by taking the form values. You can also have a new query or report in MS Access that can run " Select * from Table1". I Hope this helps.

Comment: It is helping a little bit, but I need to know how I can set the values to text fields in a form. then Update some values and then write them back.

Comment: You can see the videos on You Tube for reference. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKKgYPfq3_I